# Getting run-time error trying to use IXMLDOMNodeList

Tags: dom, msxml, vba6

Most literature on MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList is 10 years old. For some reason, Excel VBA is not letting me create the object MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList; as it gives error 429: ActiveX component can't create object. I am also having this for IXMLDOMNode
After some reading I looked and noticed I have these in my c:\windows\system32 folder: msxml3.dll, msxml3r.dll, msxml6.dll, msxml6r.dll. Which to me seems like I should have access to all DOM object types.